# Tomcat Multiple Localhost Instances

Tags: apache, tomcat, localhost, instances

What is the smartest way to configure Tomcat to have two localhost instances?

Please note that I do not have admin rights to the system, and so don't have access to the /etc/hosts file. I would love to be able to do something like the following, but can't modify my /etc/hosts files:
http://juststuffreally.blogspot.com/2007/03/enabling-multiple-localhost-sites-in.html

I'd like to have something like this, so that my instances of localhost would look as follows:

keith.localhost.com
joe.localhost.com

...but I can't modify my /etc/hosts file =-(

Another resource that I found was this, but this gives instruction for multiple outside domains--I need multiple localhost instances:
http://iam-rakesh.blogspot.com/2009/10/hosting-multiple-domains-in-tomcat.html

Any ideas?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run multiple instances of tomcat on multiple ports.  You would need a unique `server.xml` for each instance, and each one would need different ports  defined in the appropriate `<Server>` and `<Connector>` elements.

Once everything is set up, you would specify an explicit port when connecting to the instance, e.g.:

```
- http://localhost:8080/
- http://localhost:8081/
```

[This document](http://kief.com/running-multiple-tomcat-instances-on-one-server.html) covers the process in a little more detail.

Comment: Thank you! This is now working beautifully. The following link was also extremely helpful:

Comment: I'm glad it helped!  It looks like SO may have eaten your link.

Comment: This is the link: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/08/multiple-tomcat-instances-on-single.html

Comment: I have written a Java based portable utility for automating the above steps for creating multiple instances :  http://www.javaexperience.com/run-multiple-tomcat-instances

Comment: Is there a way to detect which ports are free and can be used by a new instance? Or is there a way to let Tomcat choose randomly a free port and to tell it somehow to the user?